# Will my counter variable increment before i reach the next if statement?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to increment a counter variable (`mPressCount`) every time a button is pressed. My question is: will `mPresscount` be 1 before it gets to the third `if` statement, assuming that it was 0 when the button was clicked? In other words, when `mPressCount++;` is read, does it get incremented immediately or does the button need to be pressed again before the variable is incremented?

Here is my code:

```
mButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mPressCount < 2) {
                mButton1.setText(mWord4);
                mButton1.setClickable(false);
                mButton1Pressed = true;
                mPressCount++;
                if(mButton7Pressed) {
                    mMatchedWord4 = true;
                }
            }
            if(mPressCount == 1) {
                //im going to do something if the count is at 1 like I hope 
                //it is...Thanks for your insights everyone
            }
```

Comment: as soon as `mPressCount++;` is reached, the variable is incremented

Comment: Yes. Also, there is no "mPresscounter" in your code.

Comment: ya i just put the snippet that i needed explained... i declared the field above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If mPressCount begins at zero when your button is pressed, your first if statement

`if(mPressCount < 2)` will be executed. Including `mPressCount++;` which will make

`mPressCount = 1`

The code will continue executing down the file until it reaches the third if statement `if(mPressCount == 1)` which will be executed because as we said previously, `mPressCount = 1`

Programs are like reading, they go line by line. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Click the check by my answer if it worked for you so others can see the as an answered question :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if mPressCount = 0, mPressCount < 2, then mPressCount++ will 1,  it gets to the third if statement.
if mPressCount = 1, mPressCount < 2, then mPressCount++ will 2,  it will not gets to the third if statement